# RequireJS ignores some paths

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have following `main.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'backbone': 'backbone-min',
        'underscore': 'underscore-min',
        'loader': 'loader-min'
    }
})
```

This 'loader-min.js' file is just an *optimized* js from `loader.js`:

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore'], function () {
})
```

My HTML page contains following:

```
<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   requirejs(['loader'], function(loader) {
      ....
   })
</script>
```

Btw, as I see from Firebug console, browser load only following urls:

```
GET /js/require.js
GET /js/main.js
GET /js/loader.js !!! Notice it's loader.js, not loader-min.js
GET /js/backbone-min.js
GET /js/underscore-min.js
```

So, the problem that for module `loader` it tries to load file `loader.js`, not path configured at `main.js`. Not minified/optimized file, ignoring `requirejs.config` value.

Most strange that it still uses correct values for `backbone` and `underscore`. Mostly, but not all time. Sometimes it fails on loading `/js/backbone.js`

Seems that RequireJS starts working before `main.js` is fully loaded and interpreted by a browser. Is it expected behaviour? or something wrong with my app?

How I can make sure that `requirejs(...)` function is executed only after 'main.js' is processed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main.js file is loaded asynchronously. However this script tag (below) is parsed serially. So there is no way of predicting the order of execution (though the script below will most likely execute before the asynchronous call returns).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // require() and not requirejs()
   require(['loader'], function(loader) { 
      ....
   })
</script>
```

Add the require call at the end of your main.js file like this:

```
require.config({
// configuration.
});

require(['loader'], function(loader) { 
// callback
})
```

This way RequireJS is always "configured" before executing any require or define calls.

**Edit:**
What I do typically:

```
<script src="/js/require.js"></script> <!-- No data-main attribute -->
<script src="/js/config.js"></script> <!-- Explicitly load configuration -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseURL: "path/to/base"
    });
    require(["module"], function(module){
        // code
    });
</script>
```

This way I have explicit control over what is loaded where. It also keeps my config.js file DRY.

I usually set baseURL in my bootstrap HTML because that way I can use the same config file for my Jasmine test suite.

Comment: What if I have other modules, uniq per page and user type, not only 'loader.js'. Does it mean that there are no way to continue using them as a separate scripts and I should put all of them into one huge main.js?

Comment: I mean, is it main goal of requirejs to make it possible to use small modules and load only required code

Comment: I have edited my answer to answer both of the above questions. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I understand async loading, but I'm sure that `require()` could wait until script for `data-main` will be loaded and processed, don't see any problem here. Ok, I got it. So it's expected bug, right?

Comment: It is not a bug. RequireJS makes no assumptions about the resource referred to by data-main. You can have anything other than configuration being loaded by data-main. If that file has other require calls then it will lead to a infinitely waiting call stack.

Comment: For example, assume that your main.js did not have any configuration but only had a single require call. What happens then? All other require calls wait for main.js to load and parse, and main.js is waiting for itself. It is a cyclic dependency.